# Concatenate rows into single column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have seen the below as a solution to concatenating the values of a number of rows into a single string, however I cannot understand how it actually works.

```
DECLARE @ConcatString nvarchar(max);

SELECT @ConcatString = COALESCE(@ConcatString + ', ['+ cast([Dice1] as 
nvarchar(10)) + ']', '['+ cast([Dice1] as nvarchar(10)) + ']')
FROM  [dbo].[Dice]

SELECT @ConcatString
```

Output: [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]

Please could you explain how it works, and if there are any risks using this approach.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'r approach is called *quirky update*. There's a [great article by Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/) on it. This **can** be used and is **very fast** - but there are **side-effects** you must know about and some condtions to clear in advance in order to get a reliable result. If performance is not the most important for you, rather use other approaches like `FOR XML` or `STRING_AGG` (see the existing answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One Final Edit:** 
Updated my solution to include parenthesis.

That approach works by appending the values from dbo.dice to your variable, @concatString. It's not reliable; see [this article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/). You can use `FOR XML PATH` or `STRING_AGG` on 2017+. Both methods are nasty fast. When using `FOR XML PATH` you must include an ORDER BY if the order of items must be guaranteed. `STRING_AGG` is my favorite method by far.

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @dice TABLE (dice1 TINYINT);
INSERT @dice(dice1)
VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6);

-- Solution #1: FOR XML PATH
SELECT newString = STUFF((
SELECT   ',('+CAST(d.dice1 AS VARCHAR(8000))+')'
FROM     @dice AS d
ORDER BY d.dice1
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'');

-- Solution #2: STRING_AGG (SQL 2017+)
SELECT newString = STRING_AGG(CONCAT('(',d.dice1,')'),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY d.dice1)
FROM     @dice AS d;
```

Comment: Thank you Alan, are you suggesting that I do not use the approach I posted (it does work). I was really looking to try to understand the logic as to how the string is built up in the sql I posted.

Comment: Yes - sorry, I only pasted my code and deleted my comments. See my updated post. Yes, that method is not reliable (though I've never personally had a problem with it). The for XML PATH and STRING_AGG methods are the way to go